# Changing button formatting depending on certain criteria

Tags: c#, windows

I have a small problem but first some context

I got the background color of my buttons to change to YellowGreen if the right answer is clicked and the other three go red but my new problem is that I can't figure out how to do it so that if the answer the user clicks is wrong, the three wrong answers go red and it highlights the correct answer in green (The button the user clicks gets a bright border around it to notify that is the selected answer).

To get the original problem to work, I just did the following:

```
if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "0")
        {
            btnA.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
            btnB.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnC.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnD.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

I did the above four times for the numbers 0-4 (The four possible answers in the array; A, B, C or D on the form.

My code is now as follows:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Disables the buttons upon clicking 
        btnA.Font = new Font(btnA.Font.Name, btnA.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        btnA.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Cyan;
        btnA.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
        btnA.Enabled = false;
        btnB.Enabled = false;
        btnC.Enabled = false;
        btnD.Enabled = false;

        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "0")
        {
            btnA.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
            btnB.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnC.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnD.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "0")
        {
            iCorrect++;
            if (debugMode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Correct: " + iCorrect.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        btnB.Font = new Font(btnB.Font.Name, btnB.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        btnB.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Cyan;
        btnB.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
        btnA.Enabled = false;
        btnB.Enabled = false;
        btnC.Enabled = false;
        btnD.Enabled = false;


        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "1")
        {
            btnA.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnB.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
            btnC.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnD.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "1")
        {
            iCorrect++;
            if (debugMode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Correct: " + iCorrect.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        btnC.Font = new Font(btnC.Font.Name, btnC.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        btnC.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Cyan;
        btnC.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
        btnA.Enabled = false;
        btnB.Enabled = false;
        btnC.Enabled = false;
        btnD.Enabled = false;

        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "2")
        {
            btnA.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnB.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnC.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
            btnD.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "2")
        {
            iCorrect++;
            if (debugMode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Correct: " + iCorrect.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        btnD.Font = new Font(btnD.Font.Name, btnD.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        btnD.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Cyan;
        btnD.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
        btnA.Enabled = false;
        btnB.Enabled = false;
        btnC.Enabled = false;
        btnD.Enabled = false;

        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "3")
        {
            btnA.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnB.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnC.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnD.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        }

        if (btnA.Tag.ToString() == "3")
        {
            iCorrect++;
            if (debugMode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Correct: " + iCorrect.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I tried a few different things but it kept resulting in strange things that weren't basically what I wanted to do and I can't figure out what sort of syntax or code I'd need to use to accomplish this.

Comment: if you find yourself rewriting the same code more than one time then you need to `Refactor the code and create a Method or Interface` you could write small methods that do a foreach loop on the controls and where you are setting the buttons false you could set those to false based on the Type of Control using 1 line of code..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I see. I didn't want to repeat the code but I'm not -that- experience with methods or finding the best way to do things (I tend to do things the long way round with me being a beginner)

Comment: That's not bad +1 for showing effort as well as writing some nice code even if it's long ..I will post an example on how you can create a foreach loop that will make your code look cleaner you are free to use it and learn from it

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thank you. I have a long break over the summer and I am definitely going to practice some more. For now I need to focus on getting these buttons to behave how I want them too when a right/wrong answer is clicked and I definitely need to go back and comment for my sake if not for anyone else's!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to set the Buttons to false you could create another small method and call this in spots where you want to enable or disable the buttons here is an example of the code

```
foreach( var control in this.Controls.OfType<Button>() )
{
   control.enabled = false;
}
```

This should give you an Idea on how to use this you can also highlight the code right click and click Refactor->Extract Method will give you a Method Template you can use as well

if you want to do a longer version of looping thru specific type of controls you can do the following as well.. you should be able to follow this and add what ever conditions based on the Component Type that you are wanting to work against.. something good for you to play around with as well as learn from

`If you have TextBoxes` you would like to clear

```
YourFormName.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());


private void ClearTextBoxes(Control control)
{
    foreach(Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
         TextBox textbox = childControl as TextBox;
         if(textbox != null)
            textbox.Text = string.Empty;
         else if(childControl.Controls.Count > 0)
             ClearTextBoxes(childControl);//Recursive call here
    }
}
```

`Check the Button / Sender Name` or if you are inside of the forloop you can check for example the text.Name in the caae statement then set enabled or disabled in the switch statement. Make sure you are checking the below inside of the foreach loop

```
switch (((Button)sender).Name)
{
  case " btnA":
    {
     //sent enabled or disabled  
     break;
    }
case " btnB":
    {
       //sent enabled or disabled  
       break;
    }
//etc......
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas how I'd go about my other small problem? What's happening is if I click the button with the correct answer on, the background of the button goes green (To signify the answer is correct) and the other three buttons have the background color turn red (Incorrect answer) but I can't seem to get it right so that if the answer that the user clicks is WRONG, the background color of the incorrect answers goes red and the background of the correct answer is green (So that the user then knows which answer was the right one after they have answered)

Comment: Also, that button code disables all of the buttons when I want it so that when one of the four answer buttons is clicked, it disables all buttons besides the 'Next' button (Tried using/tweaking the code but the 'Next' button was disabled when it's meant to be only disabled until an answer has been chosen, and the hover effects on the buttons still worked (Colors etc.) ). Not quite sure why as the code was pretty similar except in a method.

Comment: you can tweak that using a `switch statement` or by getting at the `Sender name` you can do a switch {case : } statement easily tweaked I will write something for you if I have time before I leave this evening if not I can post you an example when I get home after work

Comment: That'd be great if you don't mind then I can at least see where I was going wrong with coloring the buttons depending on the correct/incorrect answer as well as the function. I think the problem may have something to do with the fact that the program only recognizes which answer is correct by using `btnA.Tag = question.CorrectAnswer;` and then in the XML file the correct answer is wrapped in tags like `<correctAnswer>Brazil</correctAnswer>`. If needed I can zip up the project if it makes it easier to see where I'm coming from

Comment: i Will add something real quick to my Answer something like this should work

Comment: OK, thank you for the help :). I basically have three pressing issues with my project (One being the problem discussed in these comments regarding the correct/incorrect green/red background color and the other two involving a score total that I couldn't get fully functioning and randomizing the location of the answer buttons). I have more details written down but it's hard to come up with a solution when I'm inexperienced and the only way for me to explain it properly is to post the source code/.zip of the project as I've tried a fair few things to figure my problems out to no avail.

Comment: I would focus on getting the solution to work then when you get that focus on getting the random positioning to work. do it in small pieces so that you don't overwhelm yourself..

Comment: Ugh, forgive me for being an idiot but `switch(Button.Name)` is throwing up the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Name.get'`

Comment: can you post your code sample that you are working with.. I think you are misunderstanding how to use or get at the `Button` name..I think if you use the forloop and do the case of the object.Name it will work much easier

Comment: `foreach (var control in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
switch (Button.Name) { case " btnA": {
//sent enabled or disabled  
                            break;
                        }
                    case " btnB":
                        {
                            //sent enabled or disabled  
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }` Not quite sure what I'm meant to change as I'm not that sure what the `.Name` part refers to?

Comment: it would be `control.Name` since you implying var control ` as Type Button does that make since..?

Comment: Yes that makes sense now. Still doesn't work properly; I can still hover over the 'disabled' buttons and they change color and whatnot upon hovering (They're meant to do that when not disabled)

Comment: I would need to see your code.. If you post it I can look at it when I get home .. just post a comment when you have updated it..

Comment: I've removed it for now since it wasn't working. Here is my project - https://www.box.com/s/6u7b9uv9lg608b8gie1h

Comment: You program does not work correctly btw when I hit the next button without selecting an answer 20 times it tells me I answered 19 correctly out of 20` possible.

Comment: I fixed your code for the hovering changing color and the code you said didn't work does work. send me an email so I can zip up your project and send it back to you.. I want to to pay attention to how I linked all 4 button `Mouse_Enter` events to a single Event also look at the code that I commented out for the `Mouse_Hover` event it gives you a good idea how to do `switch (((sender)as Control).Name)` and how to do `((sender) as Button).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;` my email is `mrcaston@yahoo.com`

Comment: I will send it tonight I pretty much put what you need to do in the previous comment..  and casting your control to do a Switch on which button you hover over to stop the changing of the background color has to do with `btnA.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat` so if you can explain to me more in detail what you need it to do then I can provide you even more help. when I get home I will email you the project later it will be 9 hrs from now..

Comment: you also need to look at how you are tracking / comparing the selected answer `meaning the control.Text of the button that was selected vs the correct response` you are comparing it against.. the project looked pretty cool btw but I did not have time to go thru all the in's and out's of what you were doing.. I think that you should create a List<string> or an string [,] to track selected vs correct because it's saying that I have correctly selected 19 out of 20 answers when I never selected any answers I just kept clicking the next button.. hope that you follow what I am saying